# Finding rows that contain string, then creating column of said string

Tags: sql

I want to query a database to see if a URL contains a string and have it return the unique identifier, url and have another column of the string that I was searching for.

So if the initial query was :

```
select c.id as id , c.url as url, 'string' as string 
from database c 
where c.url like '%hello%'
```

I want it to return

```
+-------+-------------------+--------+
|  id   |        url        | string |
+-------+-------------------+--------+
| 12345 | www.abc.com/hello | hello  |
+-------+-------------------+--------+
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: please tag the dbms you are *actually* using. i removed multiple tags that were included.

Comment: Is the `string` a parameter?

Comment: are you receiving an error with the query you posted?  Or what?

Comment: Just declare the string as a variable.

Comment: try using "where c.url like '%hello'"

Comment: Out of curiousity; you have the string you are searching for, why do you need it returned?

Comment: I want it as a separate column for ease of use for filtering

Comment: Now I am more confused; you've already filtered by it by the time you get these results.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MySQL this can help you :

```
select c.id as id , c.url as url, SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.url,'/',-1) as string
from database c
where c.url like '%hello%'
```

Comment: what if there are additional letters after, so for example, www,abc.com/hello%url=tqrs

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select c.id, c.url, x.val as string 
from database c 
  join (values ('hello')) as x(val) on c.url like '%'||x.val||'%'
```

---

Note that an alias that simply repeats the column's name is unnecessary `c.id as id` is the same as `c.id`